# Запись Rtree в файл

Tags: binary, файлы, java

Доброго времени суток.
Возникла задача - хранение RTree в файле.
Всего уровней вложенности может быть 19.

Я начал с того, что занялся проектированием заголовков файла, а именно:

1. Указал с какого по какой уровень вложенности есть в файле. (например, 8-19)
2. Какой квадрат охватывает файл (границы координат)

Задача в следующем:
Найти описание ближайшей координаты к поданной точке.

Задача по поиску ближайшей точки к заданной - не проблема.
Пугает то, что вся БД должна храниться в таких вот файлах.

Найти в каком файле(файлах) искать инфу о коориднате - не есть проблема, а вот проблема в том, чтобы максимально близко установить курсор к необходимой точке чтобы не считывать весь файл (он может быть ооочень большим).

Есть у кого-нибудь идеи ?

Подробнее:
Файл, в моем представлении, должен иметь следующую структуру:

1. Заголовки (уровни (начало-конец), границы).
2. Собственно, data.

Файл - бинарник. Информация об одном элементе имеет четкий размер в байтах.

Есть у кого-нибудь соображения по алгоритму обращения к файлу и адекватному поиску по бинарке ?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему можно не пытаться искать примерное место внутри файла, где лежит ближайший объект.

Если всё дерево в памяти не помещается, то я бы просто хранил вместе с каждым узлом позиции в файле для всех его потомков. Тогда алгоритм поиска будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
поиск_в_узле(узел, точка, файл)
    если узел листовой, то
       вернуть ближайший к точке объект из данного узла
    иначе
       ближ_объект = null
       прочитать позиции в файле для всех потомков узла
       цикл по полученным позициям
          потомок = прочитать узел из файла с позиции очередного потомка
          если расстояние от точки до потомка меньше чем до ближ_обекта, то
              ближ_объект_в_потомке = поиск_в_узле(потомок, точка, файл)
              если ближ_объект_в_потомке лучше, чем ближ_объект, то
                  ближ_объект = ближ_объект_в_потомке
       конец цикла
       вернуть ближ_объект

корень = прочитать корневой узел из файла
ближайший_объект = поиск_в_узле(корень, точка, файл)
```

Очевидная оптимизация -- храним верхние уровни дерева в памяти, и только нижние -- в файле/файлах.